# Units of time in French?

Tags: vocabulaire

I am starting to study french vocabulary. Unfortunately, there is no any lists under `unité de temps` key words in French wikipedia.

Please, help me to translate this units of time to French language:

instant

second

minute

hour

day

week

fortnight

month

quarter

half-year

year

leap year

century

hourly

daily

weekly

monthly

quarterly

semiannual

annual

century

timetable, schedule

Comment: Welcome to French Language Alexander. Please visit the Help Center: [We do ask that you look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you can't find the answer you're looking for, go ahead and ask, but do provide the context in which you found the word or expression, and tell us why you find the dictionary answer unsatisfactory](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Wiktionary is not a textbook, but dictionaries can be helpful.

Comment: [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/instant), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/hour), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/day), and more out there. If you do not find a word you are looking for or are not sure how to use it in a sentence then come back and say why you are not happy with what you found.

Comment: Is it so hard to use an English to French online dictionary?

Comment: I prefer to memorize words in groups so it would be very time costly to search every word in a dictionary. I hoped that some one in this forum knew these words. To translate other word groups ones at a time I am using online text translator http://www.online-translator.com/Default.aspx?prmtlang=en now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instant = instant

second = seconde

minute = minute

hour = heure

day = jour

week = semaine

fortnight = quinzaine

month = mois

quarter = trimestre

half-year = semestre

year = année

leap year = année bissextile

century = siècle

hourly = toutes les heures  ( an hourly bus service <=> un bus toutes les heures )

daily = quotidiennement

weekly = hebdomadaire

monthly = mensuel

quarterly = trimestriel

semiannual = semestriel

annual = annuel

century = siècle

timetable, schedule = calendrier, emploi du temps

Comment: We don not usually encourage to answer questions that are off-topic on the site. Before answering your next question you might care to read the [help centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: no translation, got it.